# How to downgrade Dart with Homebrew

Tags: dart, homebrew, aqueduct

I'm on a Mac and I upgraded to Dart 2.8 from Dart 2.7.1 by running

```
brew upgrade dart
```

as it describes in the [documentation](https://dart.dev/get-dart).

However, version 2.8 contains some breaking changes for the Aqueduct framework, so I want to downgrade to Dart 2.7.2.

I tried

```
brew install dart@2.7.2
```

but got

> Error: No available formula with the name "dart@2.7.2"

I also tried

```
brew search dart
```

but only got

> dart-lang/dart/dart ✔
>   dart-lang/dart/dart-beta
>   dart-lang/dart/dart@1
>   dart-lang/dart/dart@2
>   dartsim

There is no option to select a lower 2.x version.

How do I downgrade?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. run **`brew info dart`** and find the formula link, for example
   *From: https://github.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/blob/master/dart.rb*
2. open the formula link in your browser, it will take you to the master branch repo page

   - click **"Raw"** and take the raw url from your browser's address bar, for example
     *https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/master/dart.rb*
     (save the raw url, you will need it in step 5)
3. go back with your browser to the repo page and click **"History"**

   - scroll down until you see the version you're interested in, for example **"Updated stable branch to revision 2.7.2"**
   - click on "*Updated stable branch to revision 2.7.2*" and from the top of the diffs page take the full commit ID (hash) for example *fed6de080aef54c4f1c1df732424df37cd3e5a3e*
     (save the full commit ID (hash), you will need it in step 5)
4. run **`brew uninstall dart`**
5. install an older version of Dart with
   **`brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dart-lang/homebrew-dart/fed6de080aef54c4f1c1df732424df37cd3e5a3e/dart.rb`**

   - In the command above, the url is obtained by using the url you saved in step 2 and replacing the word **`master`** with the commit ID (hash) **`fed6de080aef54c4f1c1df732424df37cd3e5a3e`** obtained in step 3.

---

***Note:*** you can keep the older Dart version (for `brew upgrade`) if you pin it with `brew pin dart`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the packages fvm and dswitch.

Both let you change between dart versions.

Fvm for the flutter dart sdk
Dswitch for the straight dart sdk.